# How to fix separate virtual hosts serving intermingled content?

Tags: google, domains, dns, search

I tried to search Google for one of my domains. I'm hosting multiple different websites on a VPS account, they are obviously sharing the same IP address.

To my surprise, the search results on one of my domains returned a few suggestions with ANOTHER domain (of my clients website), but after the ".com" part it has a prefix to MY personal project domain. Like this: `mydomain.com/about/coffee.html`. I do a search on `mydomain.com` and I get some of the results with `myclientsdomain.com/about/coffee.html`, and it opens MY domains content, but with my clients domain being in front.

How has this happened? They are in separate "vhosts" folders, everything is set up correctly (or so I think) and now this.   Maybe there are some issues with DNS records I'm not aware of?

Comment: I am sure that DNS is not the problem. The web server is what looks at the request header and returns results. Perhaps the problem is in the configuration. Can you include some anonymous details so that we can see if there are any mistakes?

Comment: What kind of details I should add? I mean - some server configuration files or anything else?

Comment: I do not know what web server you are using, some configuration files would be a good start. If Apache, you will find /etc/apache2/apache2.conf and some configuration files under /etc/apache2/sites-available for your specific sites.

Comment: @closetnoc yeah, it's Apache on centOS. I've just updated my IP settings in PLESK, which were "IP adress: Dedicated", I've changed it to "Shared" (as it seems I missed it at the begininh. Still have to learn a lot). Could that've had something in common? And here's a httpd.conf [link]http://freetexthost.com/nj3qevqnee

Comment: Okay. From this configuration file, it looks like Apache is set up to have just one site, not set up for virtual sites. It should be including various site configurations something like this *Include sites-enabled/*. Do you have a control panel for your system?

Comment: Yep, it's Plesk control panel and there are default settings for virtual sites (default folder list for a new vhost, etc...). Sites are working as intended, no issues, control panel automatically creates a new folder for a new domain in vhosts and all that stuff, it's just these search results that I came along by accident. Not good at all for SEO, obviously. I've just resubmitted sitemap files, just in case.

Comment: If you personally go to abc.com and then to xyz.com, do you see what you expect? Some Apache installs use a vhosts(??) configuration file. It all depends upon how the package was put together. Some installs install a single site by default (I think CENTOS does this if I remember right), and others install pre-configured for virtual hosting. It looks like yours is a single site install by default and that maybe Plesk is not giving you exactly what you want by missing something. I could be wrong, but that is what I am thinking right now.

Comment: Yes, that's the thing - I get what I expect when loading any of the domains, they open what they should open (two different web sites) so I have no idea how google decided to include one path from one domain and present it with another domains name in front. Thank you for effort, I will check any possible related settings with what you've described, maybe I will stumble upon something.

Comment: I will think about how this could happen. Hopefully someone will have an idea for you. It may help to add your domain names to the comments. We can at least check a few things for you. BTW- I was never a fan of virtual host sites that create sub-directories under the main site. Generally this works okay, but it might be part of the issue if that is what is going on your site. Who knows?

Comment: Well most IPs are shared anyway, so I guess there's no other option aside separate dedicated servers (sites are not big enough for that). The website is "jaunai . lt" . When entered to google search, you can see the result at the bottom with a domain "profinish" (pointing to the first domains content). That's not how it should be.

Comment: It is a funny thing, it appears to work okay here- google.com from the U.S. It may be a bug or something related to a local Google data center or if you are using google.it or something like that. Very strange. Google can do funny things from time to time. I am confused as to how this can happen. I do not doubt you of course!

Comment: Huh? Now that's really strange in that case! Here's a screenshot of what I see: http://s10.postimg.org/3q8h023a1/str.jpg

Comment: How bizarre! I am out of ideas right now. But I will think about this I promise and see if I can come up with something. It has to be related to a single Google data center. Why it is doing this is beyond me!

Comment: Lol, thanks man, I appreciate this. If it's google's issue - I'll breath easier. Off to the gym now, I've already spent too much time for this today.

Comment: Have a good day! BTW- my gym is in my garage and in my house. It is a long trip!

Answer (score 1):

Is seem you did not specify yet where the content of myclientsdomain.com is so the default content is served on the server. **You have to set up a VirtualHost** for myclientsdomain.com.

Virtualhost setup should be something like the following:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot /www/docs/dummy-host.example.com
    ServerName dummy-host.example.com
    ErrorLog logs/dummy-host.example.com-error_log
    CustomLog logs/dummy-host.example.com-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

To stay on the **safe path** and not to fall into the same pitfall again you could set up a VirtualHost setting for you own domain too and set up just a simple parking page or redirect page on /var/www